# Why have both a postmaster and postgres executable?

Tags: postgresql

It's a little confusing how you have several executables to start postgresql, e.g. postmaster, postgres, pg_ctl.

```
postmaster -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

I know that pg_ctl is designed to simplify the process of start postgres, but postmaster and postgres appear to be the same exact binary. It appears that postmaster is a symlink to postgres. What benefit comes from doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The `postmaster` symlink appears to be historical](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-postmaster.html). I didn't even know it existed until you pointed it out.

The other two are a typical pattern for UNIX daemon applications. [`postgres`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-postgres.html) provides the server functionality, and [`pg_ctl`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pg-ctl.html) provides control client for it.

It would be possible to bundle `pg_ctl`'s functionality into `postgres`, but doing so would mean `postgres` would have to run in two modes: as a DB server, or as a client to connect to a running DB server. That's a little bit unpleasant architecturally, and would add what's essentially "dead code" (unreachable and unusable) to running PostgreSQL server instances.

Similarly, it'd be possible to remove the ability to launch a PostgreSQL server from the `postgres` executable and require you to do it via `pg_ctl`, but that'd be cumbersome, and would really annoy people who manage distribution init scripts. They usually want to bypass application startup programs and launch the daemon directly, so they can prevent it from detaching to run in the background, trap exit codes, capture stderr, etc.

Essentially: `postgres` is the low level server program. `pg_ctl` is a user tool for starting/stopping the server and other management actions. `postmaster` is an obsolete alias for `postgres`.

In general you use distribution service management (`service`, `systemctl`, `update-rc.d`, etc) if you installed PostgreSQL from packages, or `pg_ctl` if you installed from source or 3rd party binary installers that don't integrate with the operating system services system.

Comment: There is another thing to consider: (at least) on Windows `pg_ctl` will drop elevated privileges and thus allows to start Postgres through an administrative account. Running `postgres.exe` directly will fail. I don't know if that is the same on Linux (`postgres` refusing to run as root) or if this behavior (dropping elevated privileges) could have been built directly into the `postgres` binary as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Very good point, and no, that's Windows-specific; under Linux `pg_ctl` will just refuse to start `postgres` if invoked as root, and you're expected to `sudo`. Windows has the ability to drop capabilities, which Linux doesn't really, and it also has a truly horrible tool (`runas.exe`) for invoking as another user where Linux has nice, simple `sudo`, so it makes sense to do it a different way on Windows.

Comment: It was historical.  Back in in the earlier days of Postgres it used a fork-exec process to spawn instances of the DBMS, which would then attach to shared memory and synchronisation resources.  This was widely used on unix based DBMS platforms of the client-server era - Informix SE, INGRES, interbase, early versions of Sybase, Progress and probably some others worked in this way.  Even Oracle has a mode where you can bring it up in this way.  Postmaster was a gateway daemon that listened on a port (5432 by default) and spawned instances of the main server when a client connected to it.

Comment: @ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells Makes sense, and I assumed something along those lines. Amusingly, that's exactly what PostgreSQL now does on Windows since it doesn't support copy-on-write co-processes with `fork()`, so we've come full circle.